# SQL compilation error: Provided Azure storage endpoint ' Azure_StorageAccount.Queue.Core.Windows.Net.' is currently not supported

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, azure-container-service

HI I am following "Configuring an Azure Container for Loading Data" From DOCS.SNOWFLAKE.COM, I am planning to do data load from AZURE Container to Snowflake , i have followed the guideline mentioned in
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-azure-config.html, i have created AZURE Resource Group, storage account (Of StorageV2 (general purpose v2)), Container and kept csv files in Container; created queue object which provides me Azure end points to access the data from Snowflake.
I have created Storage integration object ;

while creating  AZURE stage ; i am getting following error

SQL compilation error: Provided Azure storage endpoint 'shindesnowflake.queue.core.windows.net' is currently not supported.

Comment: Is your stage pointing to the **blob.core.windows.net** endpoint as mentioned in [docs](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tables-external-azure.html#step-3-creating-a-stage-if-needed)

Comment: Thanks Sergui , it was pointing to shindesnowflake.queue.core.windows.net instead of shindesnowflake.blob.core.windows.net